# How to use Times Roman (Nimbus Roman) with fontspec under Linux and LuaLaTeX

Tags: luatex, fontspec, linux

Times Roman under Linux is usually [Nimbus Roman](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/gsfonts). If I use the `times` package, Nimbus Roman will be embedded successfully, as a Type 1 font.

Now I want to use the `fontspec` package to load it. This a minimal example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times Roman}

\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

`fontspec` says it cannot find the font TimesRoman. I have also tried

```
\setmainfont{Nimbus Roman}
\setmainfont{Nimbus Roman No 9 L}
\setmainfont{NimbusRomNo9L}
\setmainfont{NimbusRomNo9L-Regu}
```

but none of them can load it successfully.

Any hint will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem or shows what you have done untill now. Do you have a concrete error message? Which one?

Comment: Afaik `luaotfload` (used by `fontspec` to load system fonts) doesn't support `type1` fonts. So if you want to use them you will have to load them in the normal way through a `tfm`-file. Use `\setmainfont` together with `otf` or `ttf` fonts.

Comment: Which operating system, and which TeX distribution, do you use? Macs and PCs use slightly different (and differently-named) versions of `Times`.

Comment: @Mico I'm using Debian squeeze and TexLive 2011.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I have also tried to use `times` and `fontspec` at the same time, without specifying the main font in `fontspec`, but it does not work. The main font is restored to Latin Modern.

Comment: Mixing the font selection of fontspec with standard (pdflatex) font packages is possible but cumbersome and not easy to handle: You must switch font encodings. Better find out if you have an otf-times and its name. Check your system fonts. On my system (win XP) `\setmainfont{Times New Roman}` works.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the [TeX Gyre Termes](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/tgtermes/) font, which is an extended version of Nimbus Roman No9 L available as Type 1 and OpenType. It is already installed in TeX Live, so using it with LuaLaTeX should be as simple as

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}

\begin{document}
The quick brown fox jumps over the sleazy dog
\end{document}
```

#### TeX Gyre Termes:

[image: Font example of TeX Gyre Termes]

#### Nimbus Roman No9 L:

[image: Font example of Nimbus Roman No9 L]

<sub>(The font samples are from the [LaTeX Font Catalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/).)</sub>

Answer (score 4):

To sum up,

- Times Roman on Linux is Nimbus Roman
- Only `type1` format of Nimbus Roman is shipped with the system
- `fontspec` does not support `type1` font
- Mixing `fontspec` and `type1` font usage is possible but difficult

So my problem can be solved if I can get a `ttf` or `otf` format of Times Roman.

[Herbert](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/74499/19293) seems to be using Times New Roman from Windows. This way is easy if you have access to a Windows PC or a Mac.

Another way is to convert `type1` format of Nimbus Roman to `ttf` or `otf` format. There are some online font converter sites, and the conversion is very fast. After conversion, I can use `fontspec` to load Nimbus Roman directly. For those who need it,

- Nimbus Roman No9 L Regular is `/usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts/n021003l.pfb`
- Nimbus Roman No9 L Medium is `/usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts/n021004l.pfb`
- Nimbus Roman No9 L Regular Italic is `/usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts/n021023l.pfb`
- Nimbus Roman No9 L Medium Italc is `/usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts/n021024l.pfb`

But in fact I don't like this way, because it makes font management complicated. Now there are two versions of Nimbus Roman in my system.

Is there some better way to solve the problem?

(Maybe I can request the Linux distribution or TexLive to ship a `ttf` or `otf` version of Nimbus Roman?)

Comment: search for a ttf version of times in the net, you'll find a lot of download addresses

Answer (score 1):

With

```
\documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times Roman}
\begin{document}     
foo     
\end{document}
```

I get

```
voss@shania:~/Test> pdffonts test.pdf
name                          type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
----------------------------- ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
YDJOHC+Times-Roman-Identity-H CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes      5  0
```

and when running `fc-list | grep Times` I get a lot of fonts in my Linux system. And with LuaLaTeX my Times Roman installed in `~./font` is used . From the log:

```
[...]
/home/voss/.texlive2012/texmf-var/l
uatex-cache/generic/fonts/otf/temp-times-0.lua)(save: /home/voss/.texlive2012/t
exmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otf/temp-times-0.lua) 
[...]
```

Comment: So you mean you have copied Times Roman from a Windows or OS X machine? I wonder if I can use Nimbus Roman shipped with the system.

Comment: XeTeX uses fontconfig and LuaTeX its own list for searching fonts as shown above.

Answer (score -1):

`\setmainfont{Times New Roman}` this is working which is slightly different from time roman

Comment: Hi Meghana, and welcome to TeX.SX. Here answers are typically more elaborated than one line only: providing additional details, a minimal working example like other answers is very useful for the readers.